# Transcendental numbers involving primes?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, transcendental-numbers

Is the [prime zeta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_zeta_function) value

$$ P(2)=\sum_{p \in \mathrm{primes}} \frac{1}{p^2} = 0.452247420041065498506543364832247934173231343\ldots $$

a transcendental number ?

What about the following sum ?
$$\sum_{p \in \mathrm{primes}} \frac{1}{p^p} = 0.2873582513062241797364180458789322069559088\ldots $$

For the last sum, [Liouville's criterion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcendence_theory#Approximation_by_rational_numbers%3a_Liouville_to_Roth) might help because of the fast converging series.

The first sum might have been checked, as it is natural to come to such a sum.
Perhaps, it is at least known if it is irrational.