# Sum of reciprocal of primes to the primes.

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, prime-numbers, transcendental-numbers

Consider the series: 
$$\sum_{i = 1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\mathrm{Prime}(i)^{\mathrm{Prime}(i)}}$$ where Prime(i) denotes the i-th prime.

Proving the convergence of this series is trivial but finding the value to which converges has defied me so far. Mathematica says this series converges to ≈0.287358.

I tried Googling about this series and found very little information about this series.

My questions are:

What does this series converge to?
Does this series arise in any context and are there interesting trivia to be known about this series?
Is it irrational, transcendental?
Does it have a name?

Comment: It is extremely unlikely that such a series would have a sum expressible in "closed form".  Even much more basic series involving primes have no known closed form.  You might look at [OEIS sequence A094289](https://oeis.org/A094289), but that gives little more information about it, just the first 104 decimal places and programs for computing them.

Comment: I don't know if it is irrational let alone transcendental but I can suggest a suitable name for it - Sophomore's prime dream

Comment: That is a very good name.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/622704, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1344000, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1529996