# Is the sum $\sum_p \frac{1}{p^p}$ , $p$ running over the primes, transcendental?

Tags: reference-request, summation, prime-numbers, transcendental-numbers

Is the sum $$\sum_p \frac{1}{p^p}=0.2873582513062241797364\cdots $$ where $p$ runs over the primes, a transcendental number ?

I don't think that it is a Liouville-number , but I am not sure. However, the sequence $\frac{1}{p^p}$ might decrease fast enough to prove the transcendentality. However I am not sure whether it is even easy to show that the sum is irrational.

Any ideas or perhaps a reference ?

Comment: As far as I know irrationality is not even known for the sum of $1/n^n$.

Comment: @Wojowu Not a good sign concerning this sum

Comment: Hmmn. Well,for $\alpha \in (0,1)$, the prime number theorem says that the $n$-th prime is $p_n \sim n \log n$.  So your sum is (asymptotically)
$$
\sum_{p\le x}\frac{1}{p^{\alpha}} \sim \sum_{n : p_n \le x}\frac{1}{n^\alpha (\log n)^\alpha}\sim\sum_{n=2}^{x/ \log x}\frac{1}{n^\alpha (\log n)^\alpha} \sim \int_{2}^{x/\log x}\frac{dn}{n^{\alpha}(\log n)^\alpha} \sim \frac{n^{1-\alpha}}{(1-\alpha)(\log n)^{\alpha}}\Bigg\vert_{2}^{x/\log x}\sim\frac{x^{1-\alpha}}{(1-\alpha)(\log x)^{1-\alpha}(\log\log x)^{\alpha}}
$$ 
But this is heavily constrained and may not help you much.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1889641/sum-of-reciprocal-of-primes-to-the-primes, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/622704